# JSX doesn't render on conditional render alongside with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to render a component based on a variable being true or false. At the moment the condition comes up as true but the component isn't rendering at all.

Here is my code:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
   {array.map(item => {
    router.query.slug != item ? <Component /> : null;
    })}
</div>
```

My console is returning true for the condition `router.query.slug != item` so what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to return the component from map function.

Here is the example that will match your problem:

**Solution 1**

```js
<div className={styles.container}>
    {array.map(item => {
        return router.query.slug != item ? <Component /> : null;
    })}
</div>
```

**Solution 2** *with single line*

```js
<div className={styles.container}>
    {array.map(item => router.query.slug != item ? <Component /> : null)}
</div>
```

You can read about `map` function in [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `block` syntax, you need to specify the return keyword. Learn more about [arrow-function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-arrow-function/)

Try this way.

Example:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
   {array.map(item => {
     return (router.query.slug != item ? <Component /> : null)
    })}
</div>
```